# MYSQL insert from select and variables

Tags: mysql, select, insert-into

I am trying to insert values coming from a select and variable :

```
INSERT INTO routeur (`codeAdherent`, `quantiteArticle`, `dateFin`) VALUES 
(SELECT `codeAdherent` FROM adherents WHERE categorie = 'G', `quantiteArticle` = $a, `dateFin`= $b);
```

Write it with and without VALUES, with and without IN, with and without brackets but I always get an synthax error.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What types are `$a` and `$b`?

Comment: $a is an integer, $b a date

Comment: What values you want to insert in which fields? Your insert query is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
INSERT INTO routeur (codeAdherent, quantiteArticle, dateFin) 
SELECT codeAdherent, @a, @b FROM adherents WHERE categorie = 'G'
```

Comment: no change, to the try I write quantiteArticle = 1, dateFin = "2018-12-31"

Comment: what error it shows, I've edited the answer you can check now - syntax error was is where cluase

Comment: quantiteArticle and dateFin doesn't come from adherents. There are external values.

Comment: you can check now

Comment: Fantastic, I wrote :

INSERT INTO routeur (codeAdherent, quantiteArticle, dateFin) 
SELECT codeAdherent, 1, "2018-12-31" FROM adherents WHERE categorie = 'G'

and that's work. I don't really understand the synthax but the result is here.

A question : why do you change $ to @ ?

Comment: @ is used for sql variable, that's why I changed it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out :

```
INSERT INTO routeur (codeAdherent, quantiteArticle, dateFin) VALUES 
(SELECT codeAdherent FROM adherents WHERE categorie = 'G', $a, $b);
```

Comment: here under the answer :
INSERT INTO routeur (`codeAdherent`, `quantiteArticle`, `dateFin`) VALUES (SELECT * FROM adherents WHERE categorie = 'G', `quantiteArticle` = 1, `dateFin`= "2018-12-31")
MySQL a répondu: Documentation

#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'SELECT * FROM adherents WHERE categorie = 'G', `quantiteArticle` = 1, `dateFin`=' à la ligne 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to read carefully the [INSERT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) because you have got many errors.
This is the right syntax:

```
INSERT INTO routeur (codeAdherent, quantiteArticle, dateFin) 
SELECT codeAdherent, '$a', '$b'
FROM adherents 
WHERE categorie = 'G'
```

PS: To avoid the [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I want to insert not only codeAdherent but also quantiteArticle and dateFin

Comment: @Chamarejc check now

Comment: quantiteArticle and dateFin doesn't come from adherents. There are external values. Thanks for your suggestion about prepare statements

Comment: @Chamarejc in your original SQL it seems that quantity and datafin were a condition with category. Anyway I adjusted my answer.